# How i Can read, write/ append xls file in node js

Tags: node.js

I have to read xls file in node js i have tried three way but i face problem as following.
please suggesst me any possible solution for this kind of problem.

```
//first time

var office = require('office');
office.parse('test.xls', function(err, data) {
console.log(data.sheets);
});

//second time

require('xls').parse('test.xls', function(err, data) {
// xls file parsed into data
console.log(data);
});*/


//third time

var fs = require('fs');
var htmlparser = require("htmlparser");
var office = require('office');

exports.onlyText = function(test) {
test.expect(3);
var handler = new htmlparser.DefaultHandler(function (error, dom) {
    test.ok(!error, error);
var text = htmlparser.DomUtils.getElementsByTagName("P",      dom)[0].children[0].raw;
    test.strictEqual(text, '213', 'text data');
    test.done();
});
office.parse(__dirname + '/test.xls', function(err, data) {
    test.ok(!err, err);
    var parser = new htmlparser.Parser(handler);
    parser.parseComplete(data);
});
};

//error in console for all time is
//Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/node_expat.node' module.js:338
//Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/node_expat.node' module.js:338
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug https://github.com/hipchat/hubot-hipchat/issues/46

Try installing `node-expat` module.